# Anylogic-selectOutput utilization

Tags: anylogic

Student modeler here.

I am trying to model a compost system. It has three vessels for composting 20L each, which I modelled as delays. I want to make it so that incoming waste goes to vessel 1 first. When it is full, then to vessel 2 and so on.

Vessel 1 when full, starts a processing time of 20 day, after which it is emptied and put back in queue. I was trying to use 2 selectOutputs but not sure how to make the condition.

Idea of the model:
[image: Idea of the model]

Answer (score 0):

I would use batch blocks before the delays with a capacity of 20 (assuming every agent contains 1 liter).
Furthermore, you could use 1 `selectOutput` 5 block instead of 2 `selectOutput`s. The model would look something like this:

[image: screenshot]

For the conditions, you could use code like below:

```
delayVessel1.size()==0 && batch1.size()==0 && batch2.size()==0
```

By checking if the other batchsizes equal 0, you make sure you'll fill a whole batch before starting a new one for another available vessel.